# Java / iText Multi-page Tiff to PDF ByteArrayOutputStream VS File

Tags: java, pdf, itext, bytearrayoutputstream

I am trying to convert A multi-paged Tiff Image into A PDF Document using iText.

This is working when I write the document to an FileOutputStream, it converts just fine and the document opens.

What i need to do is to have a ByteArrayOutputStream as i need the blob in base64, but for some reason the byteArray only contains the pdf version after converting the base64 and not the images like it should and how FileOutputStream produces.

```
                final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
//              final FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/Users/MyName/test/testPDF.pdf"); works if i swap to using FOS
                byte[] tiffByteArrayBase = Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(base64String);
                String imgDataDouble = new String(tiffByteArrayBase);
                byte[] tiffByteArray = Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(imgDataDouble);
                
                PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(baos));

                int numberOfPages = TiffImageData.getNumberOfPages(tiffByteArray);
                System.out.println("number of pages: " + numberOfPages);
                
                ImageData tiffImage = null;
                PageSize pageSize = null;
                PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = null;
                PdfPage page = null;

                for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfPages; i++) {
                    tiffImage = ImageDataFactory.createTiff(tiffByteArray, false, i, false);
                    pageSize = new PageSize(new Rectangle(tiffImage.getWidth(), tiffImage.getHeight()));
                    page = pdfDocument.addNewPage(pageSize);
                    pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
                    System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(tiffImage.getData()));
                    pdfCanvas.addImageAt(tiffImage, 0, 0, true);
                    
                } 
                byte[] image = baos.toByteArray(); //does not produce expected bytes
```

Comment: I don't see a [`pdfDocument.close()`](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText7/java/7.0.0/com/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/PdfDocument.html#close--) - make sure you close the document before calling `baos.toByteArray()`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch that was it! intresting enough it wasnt required for the fileoutput I guess it closed it out automatically after the endpoint finished

Comment: I imagine there's a duplicate somewhere; I know I've experienced this before.

Comment: Can you add this as an answer? This helps others to quickly see the solution...